# Is there a way to represent ISODate and ObjectID fields in JSON that MongoDB will recognize?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I am trying to import a JSON file into MongoDB inside node.  Here is what I am trying to do:

```
db.open(function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
    db.collection('orgs', {safe: true}, function(err, collection) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("The 'orgs' collection doesn't exist. Creating it with sample data...");
        db.collection('orgs', function(err, collection) {
          orgs = require("../data/orgs.json");
          collection.insert(orgs, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {});
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Note that NodeJS can import JSON automatically as JSON, which is nice, but JSON does not handle objects like ISODate or ObjectID.  Here is a snippit of the JSON data I am trying to import:

./data/orgs.json:

```
  {
    "stub": "apple",
    "name":"Apple, Inc.",
    "timezone": "America/New_York",
    "currency": "USD",
    "plans": [
      {"planId":1, "dtStart": {"$date":"2012-12-07 12:34:56"}},
      {"planId":0, "dtStart": {"$date":"2012-12-05 23:45:02"}, "dtEnd": {"$date":"2012-12-07 12:34:56"}}
    ]
  }
```

I am using the mongodb native driver for Node.

I tried to use integer representation of the date, but it did not work.

Is there a way to represent ISODate and ObjectID fields in JSON that MongoDB will recognize?

Comment: We use something like:

    import ejson from 'mongodb-extended-json';
    import animals from './fixtures/Animals.json';
    ejson.deserialize(animals)

where json is like
`{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "54ebb..." }, "created" : { "$date" : "2015-02-23T23:19:54.674+0000" }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't store dates and other custom objects in `JSON`, since in supports only Strings, Numbers, Booleans and `null`'s. So, to load them from `JSON` you shall somehow restore them from their string representation. Of course, you can use `BSON` instead of `JSON` since it supports all this data types, but there is a better way to solve your problem.

Since your already using `require`  instead of `JSON.parse` to load and parse your JSON data, you can make one more step and use `JavaScript` representation of your data instead of pure `JSON`:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

module.exports = {
  stub: "apple",
  name: "Apple, Inc.",
  timezone: "America/New_York",
  currency: "USD",
  plans: [
    {
      planId: new ObjectID("1"),
      dtStart: new Date("2012-12-07 12:34:56")
    },
    { 
      planId: new ObjectID("0"),
      dtStart: new Date("2012-12-05 23:45:02"),
      dtEnd: new Date("2012-12-07 12:34:56")
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case you'll be able to use `new Date` and `new ObjectID` to create dates and object ids.

**N.B.** You can use `require('bson').ObjectID` instead of `require('mongodb').ObjectID`, the result will be the same.

Comment: Thanks - I guess that this is what I will do.  I was hoping to keep with JSON since it is data, but this seems the easiest way.  I read that ISODate can be represented as {"$date": 1234455}, but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

We use something like:

```
    import ejson from 'mongodb-extended-json';
    import animals from './fixtures/Animals.json';
    const array = ejson.deserialize(animals)
```

where json is like

`{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "54ebb..." }, "created" : { "$date" : "2015-02-23T23:19:54.674+0000" }}`